# Can't type backticks (`) in the question editor (macOS 10.11.6, Safari 10.0.1)

Tags: support, editor

Though my <kbd>`</kbd> button is working fine as I can type it in address bar and copy paste it. But the editor (and even title bar), not allowing me to type it. Which is making it hard to edit code text.

My keyboard is: http://www.logitech.com/en-in/product/multi-device-keyboard-k480

Comment: Did you mean `10.11.6`? Unable to reproduce in editor or comments.

Comment: Yes it is 10.11.6. I have updated my key board information as well.

Comment: So you can type this character *everywhere but the Stack Overflow editor*? Do you have any kind of extensions or user-scripts enabled?

Comment: Yes. For both of your questions! To add detail to second one I use, Dash lane, Polyglot and Translate with safari.

Comment: @CodyGray And once I uninstalled Polyglot it started workign! As it was using ` as shortcut key. Now should i leave this question as information to other user's or delete it?

Comment: No, leaving it with the answer is fine, in case anyone else runs into this problem. I've just retagged it, since this isn't a Stack Overflow bug. :-)

Comment: Can't reproduce on 10.11.6 too, but I'm using Chrome. Just use Chrome, man :D

Comment: At least your keyboard has a ` key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was with extension that I had installed on safari. I had [installed Polyglot](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=co.randompaper.safari.polyglot-58XDWHK3JX) (for translation) and it used <kbd>`</kbd> as *keyboard shortcut*.

Strangely it allows me  to type on (g)mail and most of the places, except here. Probably this have something to do with text editor that we use here, not sure. Thanks to **Cody Gray** for pointing me out for right direction.

Comment: The link to Polyglot doesn't work and it's not even showing up in the app store search. Has it been removed perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG I am not sure, it it is related to web-browser. Because when open it with **Safari** and **FireFoxDeveloperEdition** it works. Just checked.